# Statistical significance test for comparing two canonical correlation analyses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, canonical-correlation

I have a colleague who is comparing several different treatments of data via canonical correlation analysis.  In other words, given some time-varying signal, $a(t)$, he extracting some vector of features $v_1(t)$.  He then supposes that this is a predictor for some other vector $p(t)$.  To check this he computes the [first] canonical correlation coefficient, $R_1 = \text{CCA}(v_1(t),p(t))$.  And then he tries some new improved feature extractor, $v_2(t)$, and compares again $R_2 = \text{CCA}(v_2(t),p(t))$.

I can find tests for the situation that $R_1$, and $R_2$ are different from zero.  But what about the test that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are significantly different from each other?

Asked on behalf of a colleague, but I'd also be interested in the answer.

Comment: Note there are two elements to this, firstly there is the issue of comparing two correlation coefficients, but also that the correlations have been optimised on a finite sample of data in CCA, so presumably there needs to be a correction for that?

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something obvious, but in CCA I'm used to seeing the creation of a *pair* of canonical variates, rather than a single quantity.  So what exactly is the operation $\text{CCA}(\cdot)$ here doing?

Comment: Can one reformulate it as having matrices X, Y, and Z, and comparing 1st canonical correlation between X and Z and 1st canonical correlation between Y and Z?

Comment: @Amoeba yes, I think so, with the rows of X and Y being the vectors of features generated by the two feature extraction methods and Z being the matrix of the corresponding vectors of the properties we are interested in.

Comment: @Ben the CCA is finding the linear combinations of v1 or v2 and of p that maximises the correlations.

Comment: @Dikran: That is still unclear to me, since you mention three objects, but your question shows it to be a function of only two arguments.  So to be clearer, what is $\text{CCA}(a(t), b(t))$?

Comment: Is it $\text{CCA}(a(t),b(t)) = \max_{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}} \text{Corr} (\mathbf{u} \cdot a(t), \mathbf{v} \cdot b(t))$ or  $\text{CCA}(a(t),b(t)) = \text{arg max}_{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}} \text{ Corr} (\mathbf{u} \cdot a(t), \mathbf{v} \cdot b(t))$ or something else?

Comment: @ben the first one.  We want to know whether v1(t) or v2(t) best represents p(t), and this is to be determines according to which can be most optimally correlated (but we are not really interested in u or v themselves).  However, we also want an NHST to determine if the difference is statistically significant.

Comment: If $n$ rows (samples) of X,Y,Z are independent then you could bootstrap the rows to get confidence intervals. However, your data are time series, so very much non-independent (auto-correlated), right? How about a permutation test when you permute the columns (features) of X and Y? Test statistic is the absolute difference between canonical correlations.

Comment: @amoeba wouldn't permuting the columns of X and Y have no effect as CCA would just give you weightings (rotations) of those columns that were permuted as well?

Comment: You permute them between each other! Say there are $p$ columns in X and $q$ columns in Y. You join these in a set of $p+q$ features and randomly split into subsets of $p$ and $q$ features. This by construction should yield no difference in canonical correlations but of course there will be some difference due to sampling. Repeat this 1000 times and you have your null distribution.

Comment: I'll have to think about that, the problem is I suspect the columns are not independent so some column of X may only be meaningful in the context of the other X's so if it is swapped over to Y it may no longer be meaningful (but then CCA might not be reasonable).  Will have to think a bit!

Comment: I think that's exactly what you want to test: that X has better features (taken together) than Y. By permuting the features you might get not-so-meaningful sets of features, but this should work fine as a null distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure that the permutation test is valid as the individual features are not exchangable.  Consider features representing colours as RGB and CMYK, essentially *any* exchange of features will make the performance of the feature sets worse (because the feature is only useful in the context of their own set), and hence give a false impression about the true difference between RGB and CMYK.

Comment: Hmmm. So you are saying the original correlations with Z might be say 0.7 and 0.8, but after permutation all of them get down to say 0.4 (i.e. less than the lower of the two) and so any conclusions would be invalid? I see your point but I'm not sure I agree with this concern. Personally, I would try permuting the features and seeing whether the performance gets smaller. Anyway, I don't like my answer sitting here with negative score so I will delete it for now :-)

Comment: [cont.] However, in general if there is no exchangeability then the only generic thing that remains is bootstrapping. You can bootstrap the features in X and in Y and every time compute the difference in performance (which is CCA correlation to Z). This will give you a confidence interval for the difference. Then your test is whether the interval includes zero.

Comment: why not likelihood ratio test? you compare model 1 cca(v1, p) to model 2 cca(v1 + v2, p) and possibly also cca(v2, p) to cca(v1 + v2, p).

Answer (score 0):

I think one can quantify the difference between dimensions by quantifying the difference between the regressions of each dimension: if the regression between each component of the first dimension is orthogonal to the regression between each component of the second dimension, then the difference is the maximum it could be.